# ASP MVC 2 Change language by url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, localization, routes

I'm trying to create a languageswitch for a website with 2 or more languages.

When I follow the default route (controller/action) the `Html.ActionLink("NL", ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString(), new { language = "nl-NL" }, null)` does it's work. But when called from an Action with parameters, it (logically) only creates a link to the Controller with the current Action. The parameters are ignored.

My current route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "ProjectCategory",
            "{language}/Projects/{action}/{slug}",
            new { controller = "Projects", action = "Detail", slug = string.Empty, language = "en-US" }
        );
```

The link created with `Html.ActionLink`:

```
http://localhost/mysite/nl-NL/Projects/Detail/
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 HttpContext.Current.Request.Path.Replace("/en-US/", "/nl-NL/")
```

It's not the most elegant way, but works for me. (Of course you should replace `en-US` with the current lang)